# make physicsbody from texture with transparent background (swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, skphysicsbody

Hi i'm making an app in which I want to make a physicsbody from a texture. The textures are made in such a way that everything that isn't transparent needs to be part of the body.
[Like this picture here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BaqM.png)

So to clarify in this picture I would like that another body could pass through the middle because it's transparent.

I tried this with

```
obstacle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: shape.texture!, size: shape.size)
```

But it just gives me contact when it touches any part of the picture.

What is the best way to do this?